# running sudo command for a user in centos

Tags: sudo, centos-6

On a Centos-6.1, the user is in the root group, but he is not able to run sudo commands

```
mahmood@cluster:~$ groups
root kvm vboxusers google-otp mahmood
mahmood@cluster:~$ sudo ls
[sudo] password for mahmood:
Sorry, user mahmood is not allowed to execute '/bin/ls' as root on cluster.scu
```

Any idea on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.centos.org/docs/4/4.5/Security_Guide/s3-wstation-privileges-limitroot-sudo.html

you should edit the file : /etc/sudoers (with command visudo), and add :

user ALL=(ALL) ALL